# NSIS Installer without Admin Privileges

Tags: installation, admin, nsis, privileges

I'm trying to configure the NSIS installer to run without admin privileges. Is this possible?

I'm testing as a non-admin user because some customers don't have those privileges.

What settings in NSIS cause the installer require admin privileges?

I've tried all variations of `RequestExecutionLevel none` with no joy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To make your installer run without admin privileges, use this:

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
```

Use `admin` to make your installer require admin privileges.
From the [reference](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/RequestExecutionLevel), `none` has the same effect (emphasis mine):

> Windows Vista/7 automatically identifies NSIS installers and decides administrator privileges are required. Because of this, ***none* and *admin* have virtually the same effect**.

Comment: This works for ZIP based installers too. Just add `RequestExecutionLevel user` to the file `Contrib\zip2exe\base.nsh` (but this will remove admin privileges for _all_ ZIP based installers created from now on)